# How to invoke subclass methods from abstract class?

Tags: java, arrays, casting, abstract-class

I want to have an array of an abstract class (`Neuron`), that is filled with different subclasses (`InputNeuron`, `WorkingNeuron`). Like this:

```
private Neuron[][] neurons;

public final int[] NETWORK_LAYER_SIZES;
public final int NETWORK_SIZE;

public Network(int... sizes) {
    NETWORK_LAYER_SIZES = sizes;
    NETWORK_SIZE = sizes.length;

    neurons = new Neuron[NETWORK_SIZE][];

    for(int layer = 0; layer < NETWORK_SIZE; layer++) {
    neurons[layer] = new Neuron[NETWORK_LAYER_SIZES[layer]];

    for(int neuron = 0; neuron < NETWORK_LAYER_SIZES[layer]; neuron++) {
        if(layer == 0) {
                neurons[layer][neuron] = new InputNeuron();
            } else {
                neurons[layer][neuron] = new WorkingNeuron();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to invoke subclass methods (e.g. `addConnection(Connection c)` for `WorkingNeuron`) using the `Neuron[]`. Something like this:

```
for(int layer = 0; layer < NETWORK_SIZE; layer++) {
    for(int neuron = 0; neuron < NETWORK_LAYER_SIZES[layer]; neuron++) {
        neurons[layer][neuron].addConnection(new Connection());
    }
}
```

The problem is, that the abstract class `Neuron` does not implement the method `addConnection(Connection c)`, but the `WorkingNeuron` subclass does.

I know that I could cast `neurons[layer][neuron]` to `WorkingNeuron`, like this:

```
((WorkingNeuron) neurons[layer][neuron]).addConnection(new Connection());
```

But I want to know if there is a better / cleaner solution for this problem.

***Edit:*** Implementing the `addConnection(Connection c)` method as an abstract method in the `Neuron` class is not an option, because the method only works for `WorkingNeuron`, not for `InputNeuron`.

Comment: A super class should never know anything about the subclasses! But you can define an abstract method in the abstract super class and implement it in the subclass

Comment: It looks like your abstract class `Neuron` should have method `addConnection` since probably every type of Neuron will have connections with other neurons.

Comment: You cannot if the methods are not declard in the abstract class. You could cast, but this is a smell. I would recommend an architectual redesign.

Comment: I edited the question. Implementing `addConnection` as an abstract method will not work, because the method connects one `Neuron` to another `Neuron` in the layer before its layer. Since `InputNeuron` always is in the first layer it does not have any `Neurons` to connect to.

Comment: You are abusing inheritance. If you cannot do everything you need with the `Neuron` then you have broken your abstraction. You need to rethink your abstraction such that your processing doesn't need to know the subtype.

Comment: Maybe you have to separate  neurons[] for two arrays: Input and Working

Comment: I could change back to using one array per type of `Neuron` as I did before. I just thought that using only one array would make the code more clear.

Comment: @Jannik what's the difference between InputNeuron and WorkingNeuron in terms of interface?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko I don't know if you're familiar with neural networks and their structure, but InputNeurons only get input and hold their own value. Hidden / OutputNeurons (in my code both WorkingNeurons) get values from Input- or other hidden neurons and process them. Thats why the class `WorkingNeuron` implements way more objects and methods than the `InputNeuron` class.

Comment: @Jannik if they are so different by nature, why would you need to keep them all in a `Neuron[][]`?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko As I mentioned above, I don't need to, I used different arrays until now. But I thought the code would be easier to read / more clear, since it is easier to iterate over one array than multiple ones. It can get very confusing sometimes to have the different sizes of every layer etc. and that makes the code error-prone and complicated to maintain.

Comment: Do all `Neuron` types perform a single action?  If so you could have a `Neuron` interface that has a single method much like the `Runnable` interface (or even an abstract class) that takes a `(Bi)Function` and executes the action, in the case of `WorkingNeuron` this would be a function to "add a connection".

Comment: @Jannik I just googled some neuron articles and came across this (https://c.mql5.com/18/20/NN1__1.gif). Is your `InputNeuron` really a `Neuron` or is it just an input for neurons located at hidden/output layers?

Comment: @Gavin Every `Neuron` implements the `getValue()` method. But I didn't understand your approach?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko Actually `InputNeuron` only has 2 methods: `setValue()` and `getValue()`. But since the constructor of the `Connection` class requires a `Neuron` object to connect to, I need it to be a Neuron (for the connection between input and first hidden layer).